# Trying to convert NetCDF file to shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file containing surface sea temperatures that I want to convert into a ESRI shapefile.

I have tried following this link: https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-export-layer-to-shapefile-on-qgis/
but I cannot see the ESRI Shapefile format in the drop down list.

[image: netCDF loaded into layer]

I loaded the CDF file -> right click -> Export -> save as, and I come to this screen where I can choose the format type.

[image: no Shape file option]

There is no shapefile option and I am unsure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Shapefile is a vector format. While you can vectorize a raster, it makes no sense to Save As from a raster format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "drag and drop" your nc file onto the QGIS desktop, QGIS will read it as a raster layer as you see it.

(1) Read the NetCDF file as a mesh file.

Go to the menu: `Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer...` and select the nc file.

[image]

(2) Use [Crayfish plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/crayfish/) to export the data

Install the Crayfish plugin and you will find various tools in the Processing Toolobox. Start `Export gridded value on mesh` tool (see the image above).

In the `Export gridded value on mesh` tool window:

1. Click on a small ellipsis [...] button of the `Dataset groups`.
2. Select the data you wish to export (e.g. sea surface temperature as this example)
3. Set the `Grid Spacing` according to the required level of details.
4. Click on [Run] button.

[image]

(3) The data will include many `nan` values (such as continental area). You may want to use `Extract by attribute` tool (or any other tools) to remove `nan`.

[image]